# iPhone FBConnect security captcha pages doesnt load

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios4, facebook, fbconnect

I use FBConnect provided for iPhone Facebook integration. When I try to post something to my wall it prompts me the security captcha page and it doesnt load the image to enter text. I use following dialog for this.

```
facebook = [[Facebook alloc] initWithAppId:kFacebook_APP_ID];
[facebook dialog:@"feed" andParams:params andDelegate:self];
```

What can be the reason for this. Am I doing something wrong here?

Thank you

Comment: Which version of FBConnect are you using?

Comment: Downloaded it yesterday. So should be the latest version.

Comment: ever solve this or figure out how to avoid the dumb captcha?

Comment: No this happens time to time :(